# How to select multiple rows in 2 DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to select multiple rows in 2 datagridviews like on screenshot?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoHde.jpg)
For 1 row I did :

```
private void dataDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Selection();
}   
private void Selection()
{
    table2DataGridView.ClearSelection();
    int selected = Convert.ToInt32(table1DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index);
    if (table1DataGridView.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        table2DataGridView.Rows[selected].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

But don't know how to do with a multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To synchronize selected rows of two `DataGridView`, you can handle [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of first grid and set selected rows of second grid this way:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Index)
        .ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            if (i < this.dataGridView2.RowCount)
                this.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        });
}
```